# Using 'myClass' as a parameter in Event type in single unit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

i've defined event type:

```
TMyEvent = procedure(object: TMyClass) of object;
```

and in the same unit i have also a class definition:

```
TMyClass = class(TObject)
    ...
  private
    FOnXXX: TMyEvent;
  protected
    ...
  public
    ...
    property OnXXX: TMyEvent read FOnXXX write FOnXXX;
  published
    { Published declarations }
  end;
```

If i try to compile i get 'E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TMyEvent''.

In C++ i would use prototyping. 
Is there a way to keep them in one unit together?

Sry, if it is a duplicate, but i really didn't find any information about it.

Thanks in advance,
Peacelyk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would forward declare the class before the event declaration:

```
TMyClass = class;
TMyEvent = procedure(object: TMyClass) of object;
```

Then you should include full declartion of `TMyClass` to resolve the unsatisfied forward declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put **type** before the definition, and it must be in **Interface** section not implementation:

```
type
TMyEvent = procedure(object: TMyClass) of object;
```

Check the following link to know the [ANATOMY OF A DELPHI UNIT](http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/l/aa051199.htm)